# Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 Gradle sync failed etc etc

Tags: android

I am unable to install Android Studio.
This error comes.

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1
>
> Gradle sync failed.

I have Windows 10 ( 32bit) with 4Gb ram and i5

Is there any solution? What should I do?

I Will be very grateful please help me.

Comment: Two questions: Are you sure the download was complete? Did you download the right version for your OS?

Comment: Yes. I did. There's a android studio of 32bit but without .exe. I downloaded that and also tried another android studio of 62 bit. But none of them are working

Comment: Same error message?